# Problem with running `ng serve` on a template

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, node-modules

I recently downloaded a template from theme forest on my windows environment. I am on node version `18.12.1` but in order to successfully run npm install without conflicts, I had to downgrade to node version `16.0.0`. After successfully installing the packages, I run `ng serve` and this error came

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[16128:000002138BBA2FA0]   617195 ms: Mark-sweep 2019.7 (2088.4) -> 2007.2 (2092.2) MB, 1150.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.747, current mu = 0.178) allocation failure; scavenge might not succeed
[16128:000002138BBA2FA0]   619219 ms: Mark-sweep 2023.2 (2092.2) -> 2011.6 (2096.2) MB, 2003.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.487, current mu = 0.010) allocation failure; scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF6C8491B7F node_api_throw_syntax_error+203775
 2: 00007FF6C8411556 v8::internal::wasm::WasmCode::safepoint_table_offset+63558
 3: 00007FF6C84128C2 v8::internal::wasm::WasmCode::safepoint_table_offset+68530
 4: 00007FF6C8EB47F4 v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+116
 5: 00007FF6C8E9FB52 v8::Isolate::Exit+674
 6: 00007FF6C8D21BBC v8::internal::EmbedderStackStateScope::ExplicitScopeForTesting+124
 7: 00007FF6C8D1EDDB v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+3963
 8: 00007FF6C8D35013 v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithLightRetrySlowPath+2099
 9: 00007FF6C8D358BD v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath+93
10: 00007FF6C8D450F3 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+851
11: 00007FF6C8A36825 v8::internal::DateCache::Weekday+1349
12: 00007FF6C8F51E81 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+558193
13: 00007FF6C8F52F4D v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+562493
14: 00007FF64B24851C
```

The same error comes when I do the same procedure with the current node version.
any help???

I have added `--max-old-space-size=4076` in my system paths as was instructed by  [how to invcrease node mem size](https://support.circleci.com/hc/en-us/articles/360009208393-How-Can-I-Increase-the-Max-Memory-for-Node-) but I still got the same error.

Note that the same template runs on a different mac OS system.
it also followed the same steps I did, downgrading the node version to install the packages successfully.

Answer (score 1):

For this memory size changes and also system has that sufficient RAM. In below reference link you can Node.js default memory support.
https://medium.com/geekculture/node-js-default-memory-settings-3c0fe8a9ba1

Now, you have to change "start" scripts command in **package.json** of your project. In this I have assigned **8GB** RAM (max_old_space_size=8192).

```
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve",
  "build": "ng build",
  "test": "ng test",
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "e2e": "ng e2e"
}
```